# Sending an SMS to a mobile number using Flutter Application

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to coding and have been working on a group project to develop a flutter application. Our application needs to have the functionality of sending SMS to a mobile number (by tapping an option on the screen) through an online server. Online server needs to send the message so that the user does not have the message history in their phone (as I am working for domestic violence victims, their phones are regularly checked by the perpetrators). Both the message and the recipients information will be stored on an online database which we intend to connect with our application.
Please guide me as at how I should approach this application. Thank you.

Comment: Where you are facing issue? When user press that button, call an API and from your server you can use twilio or some other messaging service to send the SMS.

Comment: I hope you have using an API for sending SMS, Most of the API will be having a documentation. Please go through the API documentation for sending SMS.

Comment: you can flollow my answer

Comment: I am having issue in the part where we have to send text messages to contacts from database to the mobile numbers discretely. There shouldnt be a record of the messages being sent from the users phone.

Comment: @HassanRajab Did you check twilio? Use any messaging service and you can send message from server, there won't be any record on the device.